# JSPDF and Html2Canvas how to reduce pdf file size

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am working on a project and there is a DIV with a lot of html & CSS and I am using JSPDF and Html2Canvas to download this div as pdf, but the file size is too large ( 8 MB ),
is there anyway to reduce the file size?

the JS code

```
$('#print').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
let HTML_Width = $(".report").width();
let HTML_Height = $(".report").height();
let top_left_margin = 1;
let PDF_Width = HTML_Width + (top_left_margin * 2);
let PDF_Height = (PDF_Width * 1.5) + (top_left_margin * 2);
let canvas_image_width = HTML_Width;
let canvas_image_height = HTML_Height;
let totalPDFPages = Math.ceil(HTML_Height / PDF_Height) - 1;
html2canvas($(".report")[0]).then(function (canvas) {
    let imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
    let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [PDF_Width, PDF_Height]);
    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, top_left_margin, canvas_image_width, canvas_image_height);
    for (let i = 1; i <= totalPDFPages; i++) {
        pdf.addPage(PDF_Width, PDF_Height);
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, -(PDF_Height * i) + (top_left_margin * 4), canvas_image_width, canvas_image_height);
    }
    pdf.save("Report.pdf");
    $(".html-content").hide();
});
```

});